# Get count of the row depending on date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

This is my query that I'm using:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), categoryName 
FROM StuSelectCateg 
WHERE depName = 'Admisiones' timeOut>= '$Date1' 
      AND timeOut < '$Date2' 
GROUP BY categoryName
```

but it doesn't return any results.

[This is my Database](http://postimg.org/image/afhrunk4z/)

[This is the output i want but with the dates](http://postimg.org/image/seq7x3p9v/)

Comment: You're missing an `AND` in your `WHERE` clause between depName and timeOut. You need error reporting turned on and so it would tell you rather than give you a blank result. Whether that solves the issue regarding output is too hard to tell due to lack of any other information in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
where depName = 'Admisiones' timeOut>= '$Date1' and timeOut < '$Date2'
```

to

```
where depName = 'Admisiones'  and timeOut>= '$Date1' and timeOut < '$Date2'
```

You are missing `and` before `timeOut`

Answer (score -2):

Your query is not correct and missing `AND`. Try below query

```
Select count(*), categoryName 
from StuSelectCateg 
where depName = 'Admisiones' and timeOut>= '$Date1' 
      and timeOut < '$Date2' 
group by categoryName
```